# Prepopulate gridview empty datasource

Tags: asp.net

I use an gridview empty datasource for bulk insert, how would I prepopulate for instance Column A with the value of a drop down box? So far I have below, but its not working

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("YourTextBoxID");
        if(tb != null)
        {
            tb.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of _empty_ DataSorce? If it is empty, how could `RowDataBound.DatRow` be fired?

Comment: templatefields with textbox....am I using the wrong event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean with *empty* DataSource. I assume that you actully mean a DataSource which is populated automatically with a default value.

You could use a `DataTable`:

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("ColumnA");
var defText = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    tbl.Rows.Add(defText);
}
GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
GridView1.DataBind();
```